# How do I: ORDER BY COUNT(column1) from the result of: SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2

Tags: mysql, sql

Because the title is probably bad, and I'm very weak with SQL, I'll try to clarify my goal:

if:

```
SELECT DISTINCT host, author FROM t;
```

Looks like:

```
foo.com | John
bar.com | Bob
bar.com | Alice
```

How do I get results like:

```
foo.com | 1
bar.com | 2
```

Let me know if this isn't clear enough, and I will update, or respond to comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a `group by`, not `select distinct`:

```
SELECT host, count(*)
FROM t
GROUP BY host
ORDER BY count(*);
```

If you might have duplicate host/author combinations, then you might want `count(distinct author)`:

```
SELECT host, count(distinct author)
FROM t
GROUP BY host
ORDER BY count(distinct author);
```

Comment: Great! This is exactly what I needed. Thanks Gordon.  I'll mark as accepted when SO allows me to.